# Policy event triggers OnUserPreferenceChanged hang

Tags: c#, .net, freeze

We are experiencing the dreaded `OnUserPreferenceChanged` hang that has been documented extensively in another post.  When we look at the `Category` property of the `UserPreferenceChangingEventArgs` argument it has a value of `9` which corresponds to the `Policy` member of the `UserPreferenceCategory` enumeration:

Policy - Indicates user preferences for policy settings, such as user rights and access levels.

What would trigger this event?

Comment: If you want to get better answers sooner, you should edit your post (edit link below your question) and add the tags relevant to the language you are using.

Comment: This usually has more to do with getting the SystemEvents class initialized incorrectly and getting it to fire events on the wrong thread.  Usually because of a splash screen.